# How can I permanently/globally disable word wrap in kate?

Tags: kde, kate

In kate there seems to be "dynamic" and "static" word wrap options in `view -> word wrap` and `settings -> configure kate -> editing -> general` respectively.

"Static" is off by default while "dynamic" is on. Turning off "dynamic" gives the behaviour I want (i.e. no word wrap... of any kind). However, this option seems to be per file.

How can I disable word wrap in the kate text editor for all files and have that option persist?

Answer (score 5):

There is another setting you need to turn off.

Uncheck the checkbox in `settings -> configure kate -> Editor Component -> Appearance -> Dynamic Word Wrap` and it should now work the way you want.